# How to (properly) use form requests + policies + resource routes with dependencies?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, authentication, policy

My use case is that an user is/owns a company, which has employees.

Using form controllers along with model policies i am trying to figure out what the best/proper way to do it should be.

routes:

```
    Route::resource('company', \App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\CompanyController::class);
    Route::resource('employee', \App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\EmployeeController::class);
```

employee store request:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Models\Employee;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class EmployeeStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return $this->user()->can('create', Employee::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'company_id' => 'required|integer|exists:companies,id'
        ];
    }
}
```

employee policy:

```
...
/**
 * Determine whether the user can create employees.
 *
 * @param  \App\User $user
 * @return mixed
 */
public function create(User $user)
{
    return $user->can('update', Company::find(
        app('request')->get('company_id')
    ));
}
...
```

So i am not particularly happy in how the policy checks if the user can edit the company the employee will belong to, since this only happens on http, for console/tests this will break.

Then the most logical way to add this check is in the form request's authorize() function, but then you are checking permissions outside the policies, which sounds illogical.

So in short, the question: how & why would you do this using form requests & model policies?

Answer (score 3):

You only need to add the `id` of the company to the `EmployeePolicy@create` method, and you will be able to use it outside http

`EmployeePolicy`

```
public function create(User $user, $companyId)
{
    return $user->can('update', $companyId);
}
```

`EmployeeStoreRequest`

```
public function authorize()
{
    return $this->user()->can('create', Employee::class, $this->request->get('company_id'));
}
```

You can test it outside http with `tinker`

```
php artisan tinker
$user = User::find(2); // or whatever user you want to test with
$user->can('create', Employee::class, 3); // 3 = company_id
```

Comment: Are you sure this line is correct? `return $user->can('update', $companyId);`. Like how is Laravel supposed to know to check `CompanyPolicy` in this case?
I find `return $user->can('update', Company::class, $companyId);` more appropriate, like you did in `EmployeStoreRequest`